# Can't run rtabmap from roslaunch

Tags: slam, navigation, launch-file, rtabmap, rtabmap-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed **rtabmap** with `$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-rtabmap-ros` but I'm not able to launch it as expected:

```
$ roslaunch rtabmap_ros rtabmap.launch
[rtabmap.launch] is neither a launch file in package [rtabmap_ros] nor is [rtabmap_ros] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

Because I installed a premade binary do I need to create my own launch files? If so, where/how do I do that?

I've tried to build from source but I'm running into a number of pcl/openni issues. Both are installed and working but I believe there's some sort of conflict with how I built one or both of them. Unfortunately the error output is so long that it fills up the terminal so far that I can't even scroll up to see the beginning. I'm recompiling PCL right now with all related options enabled to see if that will help (it's taking some time).

Suggestions?

** EDIT **

I trying to compile on both an `armv7` and `x86_64`. Here's the much smaller error output of the `armv7`:

```
$ make
[  6%] Built target rtabmap_utilite
[  7%] Built target res_tool
[ 42%] Built target rtabmap_core
[ 87%] Built target rtabmap_gui
Linking CXX executable ../../../bin/rtabmap
../../../bin/librtabmap_core.so.0.11.4: undefined reference to `pcl::OrganizedFastMesh<pcl::PointXYZRGBNormal>::performReconstruction(pcl::PolygonMesh&)'
../../../bin/librtabmap_core.so.0.11.4: undefined reference to `pcl::OrganizedFastMesh<pcl::PointXYZRGBNormal>::performReconstruction(std::vector<pcl::Vertices, std::allocator<pcl::Vertices> >&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [../bin/rtabmap] Error 1
make[1]: *** [app/src/CMakeFiles/rtabmap.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Do I need to add the `OrganizedFastMesh` file somewhere?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232308/can%27t-run-rtabmap-from-roslaunch/) by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 396 on 2016-04-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2016-04-20**:
The binaries (0.10) don't install `rtabmap.launch`. You can have the same functionality with `rgbd_mapping.launch` or `stereo_mapping.launch` like in the [tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/HandHeldMapping).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This was either a PCL or OpenNi issue but I'm not sure which. I reformatted my pc and installed ROS followed by rtabmap and everything worked fine.

I may have been able to install https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros.git anyway but I had reinstalled Ubuntu before I found out I could build the rtabmap launch tools independently.

---

Originally posted by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) with karma: 396 on 2016-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0